# Visual Studio 2015 не видит Microsoft.Office

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2015, office

Хочу сделать приложение, которое будет записывать данные из программы в Excel файл, но при написании этих 2-х строк:

```
private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet workSheet;
private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application excelApp;
```

пишет что "Тип или имя пространства имен "Office" не существует в пространстве имен "Microsoft". Залез в пункт References -> Add Reference -> Assemblies -> Extensions и не обнаружил там ничего похожего на офис. Кто подскажет в чем может быть проблема и как ее решить?

Comment: добавь руками необходимую ссылку на библиотеку. у меня, например, здесь лежит: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\DCF\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll`

Comment: @slippyk c новым годом) проверил все файлы в папках от офиса 13-го на наличие каких либо dll в которых есть название Excel, нашелся единственный файл - excelcnvpxy.dll Переустановка офиса и вижлы не помогла.

Comment: [Здесь](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508) все есть, можно скачать и установить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установка офиса с сайта microsoft и переустановка Visual Studio 2015 не помогли. Помогла установка Visual Studio 2017 в которой есть компонент "Разработка для Office и SharePoint". После установки данного компонента все заработало.